# Select specific columns from Eloquent relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have the following models in my application:

**User.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function customer_details()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CustomerDetails::class);
    }
}
```

**CustomerDetails.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerDetails extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to run the following query:

```php
$user = User::select('email', 'phone')
    ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->with('customer_details')
    ->first();
```

Now what I want it to do is to select only the **email** and **phone** number from my **users** table and **first_name**, **last_name** from my **customer_details** table but whenever I try this it always returns **customer_details** as `null`.

Comment: In your User.php file you missed to specify localKey to compare with foreign key:

`return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CustomerDetails', 'user_id');`
It should be : 
`return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CustomerDetails', 'user_id','id');`

Comment: Note for a 7 year old question: the general question has value, but the specific problem could have been avoided with `$user = Auth::user()->load("customer_details");`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to include the `id` in your select, otherwise the eager loading has nothing to match against. I just tested this against my own project and ran into the same issue, adding the `id` to the select fixes it.

```
$user = User::select('id', 'email', 'phone')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('customer_details')->first();
```

To further explain this, eager loading works by making your parent call first (in this case, the call to `users`) and then doing a second call like `SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE customer_details.user_id IN (?)` where `?` is a list of user IDs. It then loops through the results from that second call and attaches them to the appropriate user objects. Without the `id` on the user objects, there's nothing to match against in the second call or when attaching.

EDIT

To select specific columns from an eagerly loaded table, you can use the closure capabilities explained [here](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/column-selection-in-eager-loading). So you use the relationship name as the key and a closure that receives a `Builder` object as the value, like so:

```
$user = User::select('id', 'email', 'phone')
    ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->with('customer_details' => function (Builder $query) {
        $query->select('id', 'user_id', 'name', 'foo');
    })
    ->first();
```

Note that you *must* select the relationship column for both, otherwise Laravel has no idea how to connect the two

Comment: Thank you that worked :) i gotta ask though how do i then select only specific columns from "customer_details" as well?

Comment: @user3718908 Please see the edit I just made to my answer

Comment: The code with the closure, there is something wrong with it, it gets underlined in red, i took out 'Builder' and left it as '$query' alone. It works now. :)

Comment: You would have to import the Builder class (`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;`)

Comment: Yes really correct answer and explanations.  "Note that you must select the relationship column for both, otherwise Laravel has no idea how to connect the two" this is the real answer

Comment: Your code to select specific columns give error on Laravel 7. Update the "with" section by the following code:


    ->with(array('customer_details' => function ($query) {$query->select('id', 'user_id', 
    'name', 'foo');}))

Answer (score -1):

I think your select is bad.  Use query builder in laravel.

try this

```
$user=DB::table('users')->join('customer_details','user.id','=','customer_details.id')->select('email','phone','first_name','last_name')->where('id','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

I suppose that you use also id as primary key in customer_details.

Answer (score -1):

In your User.php file you missed to specify localKey to compare with foreign key:

`return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CustomerDetails', 'user_id');`

It should be : There is a 3 parameter : ( Model, 'Compare key with', 'Local key')

`return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CustomerDetails', 'user_id','id');`

Answer (score -1):

This absolutely correct.If you have thrown an exception error with this code.
like this
eg
"error": "mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

```
    $user = User::select('id', 'email', 'phone')
            ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->with('customer_details' => function (Builder $query) {
             $query->select('id', 'user_id', 'name', 'foo');
        })->first();
```

then use just [] in with  like this

```
$user = User::select('id', 'email', 'phone')
        ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->with(['customer_details' => function (Builder $query) {
       $query->select('id', 'user_id', 'name', 'foo');
}])->first();
```