# How to select specific column in eloquent relationship inside the Model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

**EDITED:** Guys can you review your suggested duplicate? I did some research before I ask this question, and I'm already to that link, that is not the answer that I'm looking for.

---

How can I pluck specific column in eloquent relationship? I want only `name` column to be returned when I `Student::find()->subject;`

I tried the below codes but doesn't work and returns me an error

> App\Student::subject must return a relationship instance.

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subjects';
    protected $fillables = ['id', 'name', 'gender', 'birthdate', etc.];

    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subject')->pluck('name');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select specific columns from Eloquent relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727060/select-specific-columns-from-eloquent-relations)

Comment: @Collin I think this is not duplicate to that, bdw you can review it if its really duplicate, 've been there to that link before I ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any query builder functions on the relation.
Use `select` to only select the name column

```
public function subject()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subject')->select('name');
}
```